# Do all finite groups contain an odd number of elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Hello ive got a maybe weird and primitive question, which purely comes from my status as a beginner. Thinking about groups and their properties, with $\forall a \in G\,\,\, \exists a^{-1} \in G:aa^{-1}=e$ and the existence of a neutral element $e \in G$, doesnt this gives us the information, that any group, disregarding how large has a odd number of elements? And Cant we translate something into non-finite groups? This really interests me. Maybe someone can give me insight on how to look at this, and how to win or not win any information for non-finite sets.

Comment: That assumes that $a^{-1}\neq a.$ Indeed, if $G$ is a finite group such that $a=a^{-1}$ has no solution Other than $a=e,$ then $G$ has an odd number of elements.

Comment: You don't know for sure that $a$ and $a^{-1}$ aren't the same element. For a simple example, consider that the group of integers mod $n$ with addition, for each $n$. This is a group with exactly $n$ elements.

Comment: If $G$ has an even number of elements, your argument shows that there is an odd number of $a\neq e$ such that $a=a^{-1}.$

Comment: Dihedral group of symmetry of any degree (n) always has even no. of elements (2n).

Comment: This is a great question to ask, by the way. It would make a good true or false question on an exam for a first group theory course.

Comment: @Elliot G That could be a good question for the first homework assignment, but for an exam? I don't see how anyone might think every finite group has odd number of elements at the end of a full course in group theory.

Comment: @Mark I guess I meant more of a "find the flaw in this logic." I've always liked those types of problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the group $\mathbb{Z_n}=\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$ where the operation is addition modulo $n$ is a group with $n$ elements.

Note that some elements satisfy $a=a^{-1}$, so $a$ and $a^{-1}$ are not always $2$ different elements. This is your mistake.

Comment: Ohh thank you :)